# VBA AutoFilter with symbol (*) Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter excel data using AutoFilter, but somehow it is not working. 
The data I want to filter represent time and are in format of 00:00 through 23:59.
Specifically, I am trying to filter by the hour, so like "00" through "23", or "00:" through "23:", whichever works. 
However, it is not working and none of them gets filtered.

Assuming there is a table like

|ID|Date| time | 
| 0 | 7/5 | 00:00| 
| 1 | 7/5 | 00:20| 
| 2 | 7/5 | 00:35| 
| 3 | 7/5 | 00:47| 
| 4 | 7/5 | 00:58| 
| 5 | 7/5 | 01:03| 
| 6 | 7/5 | 01:15| 
| 7 | 7/5 | 01:27| 
| 8 | 7/5 | 01:48| 

I tested the following macro:

```
Selection.Autofilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=00*"
```

hoping that I could get the top 5 rows of the data as their times begin with "00". I looked for information on how to set "start with" in AutoFilter, and I found that star (*) can be used. However, this does not work and none of the rows gets filtered.
Interestingly, if I tried the following:

```
Selection.Autofilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="00:20"
```

it worked fine and it filtered the second row only where the time is "00:20".

Why is my first macro with * not working? I tried many different ways to no avail. Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Comment: `Criteria1="=00*"`  ----->  `Criteria1:="=00*"` (dont forget the *column* after parameters' names).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It was a typo and in the real program, it has the colon there.

Comment: What are you selecting when you run the macro? And why use `Selection` at all !? Try running it on an explicit, fully qualified range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel treats time values as decimal numbers. One approach would be is to insert a helper column called "Hour" and put the following formula in D2

```
=HOUR(C2)
```

and copy it down.

Now filter the data like below...

```
Range("$A$1:$D1").Autofilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=0"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was new to Excel Macro, and did not know the data had different types. I thought they were all strings. I used this as a hint and I managed to get it to work. Appreciate it everyone for help!